# Large banners - InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to design four panel booth design W: 0.5 x 5.5 x 2.5 x 0.5m and H: 2.5m. What would be the best way to start and save the files. 5.5m is too big for InDesign.

Comment: How is a panel supposed to have four different widths? Are you talking about four different documents? There are many questions here about making large banners; you should use the search function and look through them before asking, to see if any of them answer your question for you.

Comment: Thanks Janus. It is a booth with 4 walls. I will check the links you have provided. Many thanks

Comment: @Scott I disagree with that dupe. Both answers on that Q only go into resolution, and not into how to set it up in ID.

Answer (score 2):

InDesign is perfectly capable of handling this, provided you work on scale. Have a chat with the printer / producer of the booth, and they will most probably tell you to create your printing files in scale 1:10 or similar. Mine always do.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using InDesign for panel graphics. It's mainly for document design. For large format graphics I reccomend using Illustrator.

I believe the largest artboard size in Illustrator is 220 inches, but you achieve 5.5 meters by designing in fractions.

25% of 5.5 meters is 137.5 centimeters, so make an artboard that size or at the fraction you want. When exporting your art you can blow it up 400% or this can happen at the printers end.

A word of caution: vector art will scale up nicely but if you have photographic content you should make sure it looks sharp at 5.5 meters big.

Comment: Why do you recommend Illustrator? I have been using ID for panel graphics for years and I heavily prefer it over Illustrator for this kind of work.

Comment: I just recommended what I know best. I was unaware ID could have varying size art boards placed above or next to each other share elements and background. While this poster seems to be asking about 4 equal panels attached as columns to make a single image booth backdrop, you can arrange more complex panel displays in Illustrator. Additionally the backdrop image can contain (for example) a single wall size photograph across all 4 panels, and I haven't seen that done in ID.

Comment: Ah, a panel mosaic is indeed a good reason, I wouldn't know how to do that in ID indeed. Thanks!